# (SpringBoot) Dockerizing my application with a MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

My application is functional when I'm running it on localhost and I've even deployed it to Azure Cloud and it works, but I can't run it on docker.

Here are my configuration files :

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/games
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=annotated
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
db:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: src/main/resources/Dockerfile
container_name: db
restart: on-failure
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1234'
MYSQL_DATABASE: 'games'
MYSQL_USER: 'root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD: '1234'
ports:
- '3306:3306'
backend:
build:
context: .
container_name: backend
restart: on-failure
ports:
- '8080:8080'
depends_on:
- db
links:
- db
```

Dockerfile from the root directory

```
FROM maven as build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
FROM openjdk:17-jdk
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Dockerfile from the root/main/resources (here I also have a data.sql file, my exported database)

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_DATASOURCE_URL=${MYSQL_DATASOURCE_URL}
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
ENV MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
COPY ./src/main/resources/data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
EXPOSE 3306
```

After I'm running docker-compose build, I'm getting this:

30.84 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure30.8430.84 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: If `docker-compose build` is producing that error, something in your build system is trying to connect to the database, but an image build can never connect to another container.  Do you know what _during the build_ is trying to connect to the database?